# How to test if a string contains a number with regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying with

```
function hasANumber(value) {
    return /^.*[0-9]*.*$/.test(value);
}
```

Where I was wrong?

Comment: if you want just to check whether string has at least one digit - `/[0-9]+/`

Answer (score 1):

`*` in regex means zero or more

You should have used `+` which means one or more, as in:

`/^.*[0-9]+.*$/`

Although this can be simplified to:

`/[0-9]+/`

Answer (score 1):

Just `\d` would be enough for this case.

```
> /\d/.test('foo')
false
> /\d/.test('fo1o')
true
```

`[0-9]*` in your regex matches a digit zero or more times, so it would allow also the strings which won't have a digit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct form to write the number regex is :

```
 \d+$
```